# CSS Less -ms-filter mixin

Tags: less, mixins

I have the following CSS LESS mixin:

```
.transparency (@amount, @tranc) {
    background: rgba(red(@amount), green(@amount), blue(@amount), @tranc);
}
```

and the way i use it is:

```
.transparency (#FFFFFF, 0.2);
```

but i need to find some way of including -ms-filter in the mixin... but i am not quiet sure, i used on online generator and it gave me this result:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#B224417C,endColorstr=#B224417C)"; /* IE8 */
```

how would i include this? I mean the startColorstr and the endColorstr...

Any help Greatly Apreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated the function with the following:

```
.transparency (@colour, @alpha) {
    @alphaColour: hsla(hue(@colour), saturation(@colour), lightness(@colour), @alpha);
    @ieAlphaColour: argb(@alphaColour);

    background-color: @colour; // Fallback for older browsers
    background-color: @alphaColour; 

    // IE hacks
    zoom: 1; // hasLayout
    background-color: transparent\9;
    -ms-filter:  "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=@{ieAlphaColour}, endColorstr=@{ieAlphaColour})"; // IE 8+
        filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=@{ieAlphaColour}, endColorstr=@{ieAlphaColour})"; // IE 6 & 7
}
```